# How to stop updating the database if the input file not selected?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, sql-server-2012

My setup is like this,

1. Users enters values in a JSP page. In the same page I've given an option to upload a file.
2. When users click on Save button at the end, it redirects to a servlet and the values including the file gets uploaded into DB (I'm using SQL Server)

If users do not upload any file and click on save, the query to update in the servlet is updating with '0x' for the File(ProgressFile in DB) column. But I don't want to update DB when there's no file selected to upload.

In My JSP, `<INPUT NAME="file" TYPE="file">`

In My Servlet,

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
String File = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
if (filePart != null) {
            // obtains input stream of the upload file
        inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
}
String query = "Update helpData SET ProgressFile = ?, ProgressFileName = ? where ID='"+ID+"'";      
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(2, File);
//method to insert a stream of bytes
pstmt.setBlob(1, inputStream ); 
int row = pstmt.executeUpdate();     
if (row > 0) {
     System.out.println( "File uploaded and saved into database");
}
```

How to not to update the DB when there is no file selected for upload?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: add you update code into 
if(filePart != null){
//   put here ur code which udpates db 
}

Comment: i tried that. But it's not working

Comment: check column type there column matching issue send me ur code

Comment: I've set the column type to varbinary(max). If I upload any file its getting uploaded into DB also and I'm able to download that as well

Comment: add client side validation using jquery , it check if check file is not selected then form button should not b workable

Comment: updated my code with 
if (!File.equals("")){//code which updates DB}
and it worked

Comment: @kishoresrivatsa : you can even go ahead with front end validation rather then changing the server side code .